# How to process an email thread with mailman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmail, mailman

If the person replying to a "ticket" is using a mail client such as gmail that reply will show a whole conversation thread when I do `@message.body.decoded` rather than the text that they typed.

Is there a way to extract just that portion of text?

Comment: only thing I can think of is to put for every message going out, and for a message going it to do a diff on the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the existing replies are formatted with a preceding `>`. One option is to extract lines that do not begin with that character.

So you look at the email as plain-text, you can extract it. Here is an example:

```
--f46d0basically0a0unique0id # Marks the start of content for this email
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Hello foo,

This is a message.

Regards,
Bar

>
> Original response
> is quoted like this
> What in included here 
> depends on mail client
>


--f46d0basically0a0unique0id # Marks the end of content for this email
```

Comment: this looks like the most reasonably solution, except if contacts start using > in the start of their lines for no reason. but that's a tiny caveat.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution because messages use `>` but also mix it with original messages in html.

Comment: I think I need to separate the first unique section, and then remove the `>`s

Comment: Yeah, its just a hacky work around. But I know for sure that GMail guys match it with last email's content.